# AC line surge protection with GDT in series with MOV

Tags: ac, protection, surge-protection, mov, gdt

We often use GDT in series with MOV to protect AC lines as below.

[image: Source : EPCOS Surge Arrestors-pp]

But i have Question as for 230V AC line and 275V Rated MOV - What Should be the Breakdown voltage of GDT ?

Three options available :

1. 270V
2. 470V
3. 600V

Comment: Please remove the ALL CAPS from the title, just use non-capital letters like everyone else.

Comment: ok thanks Bimpelrekkie

Comment: Where did the circuit come from i.e. what website?

Comment: https://www.tdk-electronics.tdk.com/download/174146/5dda6a276e51515ffdf5a9efb103de29/surge-arresters-pp.pdf

Page 23/88

Answer (score 1):

The linked document in the comments below the question is about gas-discharge surge arresters and the picture you embedded in your question cut-off vital detail: -

[image]

> What Should be the Breakdown voltage of GDT ?

For a 230 V AC line you can use either a 470 volt or 600 volt GDT as listed at the top of the drawing above.

Comment: That is ok ,but based on above rating 470 & 600 V , which is best suitable ?

Comment: That depends on the surge withstand capability of the product and what level of surges the product is to be tested against. EN 61000-4-5 gives several levels that a product should be tested against i.e. 500 volts, 1,000 volts, 2,000 volts and 4,000 volts. At too high a surge level test the lower voltage device might fail (as might also the MOVs) but, the 600 volt device might not quite protect well-enough for the actual product the circuit is intended to protect.

Comment: @AnilKG if we're all done with this Q and A session now maybe you should [take the 2 minute tour](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/tour) to see what you should be considering next.